# how to write bch commands in bash file

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script to get block count . It is giving error

./script.sh: line 4: =: command not found

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
# getblockcount
$blockcount = bitcoin-cli getblockcount
echo $blockcount
```

Kindly tell what is wrong .

Comment: sorry , its on line 3 not 4
./script.sh: line 3: =: command not found

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bitcoin. Bash Scripting should be asked on Stack Overflow

Comment: @RaghavSood I updated it

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would identify this problem automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be space around the operator.. So remove the space around `=` and thing should work. Also there are some other bits.. Here is the corrected one.. Ensure command `bitcoin-cli getblockcount` from terminal  gives right result.

```
#!/bin/bash
# getblockcount
blockcount=$(bitcoin-cli getblockcount)
echo $blockcount
```

Comment: You need quotes around the expansion: `echo "$blockcount"`. See [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), or [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Also, note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "*...have been asked and answered many times before*".